# Angular JS Jasmine Testing - Multiple Changes in Variable Value in Chained Promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

I have a chained promise that looks like:

```
myService.methodOne().then(function(){
    $scope.myVariable = true;
    return myService.methodTwo();
})
.then(function(){
    $scope.myVariable = false;
});
```

How would I test that `myVariable` was first assigned to `true` then to `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm assuming you're testing a function that you have on the $scope of a controller,

e.g. `$scope.someFunction = function () {
    myService.methodOne().then(function(){
        $scope.myVariable = true;
        return myService.methodTwo();
    })
    .then(function(){
        $scope.myVariable = false;
    }); 
};`

You could inject $q (and the necessary services) into your tests:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('module.with.service');
    angular.mock.module('module.with.controller');

    inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_, _myService_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $q = _$q_;

        myService = _myService_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });
});
```

For your actual test, create two separate promises:

`var deferred_methodOne = $q.defer(),
     deferred_methodTwo = $q.defer();`

Then place two spies on myService (one spy per method) that returns the promise corresponding to the method:

`spyOn(myService, 'methodOne').and.returnValue(deferred_methodOne.promise);
 spyOn(myService, 'methodTwo').and.returnValue(deferred_methodTwo.promise);`

After the initial setup, initialize your controller and make the call to the function you're testing:

`$controller('TestController', {
     $scope: $scope,
     myService: myService
 });
 $scope.someFunction();`

Then you can trigger the promises individually, and test the outcome of each trigger (note that you need to trigger a digest cycle in order for a promise's resolve() or reject() to take effect in $q):

```
deferred_methodOne.resolve(); // resolve the first promise
$rootScope.$apply(); // trigger a digest cycle  
expect($scope.myVariable).toBe(true); // test the first condition

deferred_methodTwo.resolve(); // resolve the second promise
$rootScope.apply(); // trigger a digest cycle 
expect($scope.myVariable).toBe(false); // test the second condition
```